# How do I remove the ‘Please remove the installation medium, then press Enter.‘ screen?

Tags: 20.04

I am working on modifying a live image of ubuntu for use as a bootable DVD. I have the image almost exactly as I want it, but I cannot find what to remove or modify to eliminate the ‘ Please remove the installation medium, then press Enter.’ screen.

How do I remove this screen from a live image?

Comment: If you remove the message, then the user won't know that the installation is complete.

Comment: What's the programme are you using to customize Ubuntu 20.04 image??

Comment: **To the close voters:** note that that creating the installation medium is on topic since that is presumably being done on an Ubuntu machine. However, if someone now uses that medium to install a system, then the system they have installed is not an official Ubuntu and, therefore, questions about that system is off topic.

Comment: @user535733 in my use case, the user has no ability to install using the live disc anyway. The ubuiquity package that gives the user the option to install Ubuntu has been removed.

Comment: @UnKNOWn [Cubic](https://launchpad.net/cubic)

Comment: A useful (and easier) alternative to mucking about with editing a Live image is to customize a real, installed system, then use [overlayroot](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/admin/overlayroot) to prevent users (and some admins) from making any persistent changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the bootcode `noprompt` to the appropriate lines `txt.cfg/grub.cfg`.